# Django __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given (added .as_view())

Tags: django, database, api

After I run the server and go to the .../api/user it return an error

```
File ".../project/user/views.py", line 21, in get
return Response(serializer.data)
```

`TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

**Attention** line 21: in get
   **return Response(serializer.data)**

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
class UserInfo(APIView):
   def get(self, request, format=None):
       user = User.objects.all()
       serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)
```

**user/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/', UserInfo.as_view(), name='list_user')

]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('user.urls'))
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

I had added .as_view().

Comment: Seems you are not calling the correct URL? Shouldn't be /api/user/?

Comment: Have you tried calling `return Response()` without any arguments?

Comment: this is http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/ i called. Could you help me?

Comment: ```Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'requests.models.Response'>` ``` result when i edited `return Response()`

Comment: Can you post all imports and also full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on that comment

> Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'requests.models.Response'>` result when i edited return Response()

you've imported the wrong `Response()`. You'll have to import one from DRF, not from Requests.